# OpenCV IMread issue with windows form app

Tags: winforms, image, opencv

I have an application that loads an image, so i use:

```
image1 = imread("Cam_Pic.jpeg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

And then I do some face detection code and save it to a file to then show it on my windows form. It works perfectly if i only do it once. To give you a little background. This is kinda how my code works:

- I "click" button on form
- my camera takes pic & saves it as a JPEG image
- Picture is read by imread
- haar cascade is used to detect face
- rectangle is placed around detectedface
- THAT image is saved to new JPEG
- Form loads the the new JPEG image (with rectangle around face)

This works perfectly if I only do it ONCE. If i press the button again, the camera will take the picture, but my "face_detect" function will gave me an IMREAD error this time saying it can't read the pic taken by the camera, but it is there. Here's my code, or part of it:

```
void Face_detect()
{
    Mat image1;
    Mat grayscaleFrame;

    //image1 = cam_cap;

    //G E T   I M A G E 
    image1 = imread("Cam_Pic.jpeg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if (image1.empty())
    {
        cout << "!!! Failed imread(): image not found" << endl;
    }

.
.
.
.

imwrite("Detected_image.jpeg", image1);
}


/////////// W I N D O W S  F O R M /////////////////

    private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
             {
                 // snap picture
                 PlaySound(L"Eagle_img_analyzing.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
                 Eagle.saveImage("Cam_Pic.jpeg");
                 Face_detect();
                 PlaySound(L"Eagle_Analysis_complete.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
                 pictureBox1-> Load("Detected_image.jpeg");

             }
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Why would you save the camera picture, then reload it?

Comment: It's easier for me to handle the JPEG image that way. I know it's inneficient but I'm aming for practicallity right now.

Comment: Can we see the code where you save the picture?